# "bash: rvm: command not found" after multi-user install

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I have followed the instructions of how to do a multi-user install of rvm on Ubuntu. I did not do this as root. When i  do "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" then I can use rvm. However if I log out and log in again and do "rvm -v" I get "bash: rvm: command not found". Can I make it so that I don't have to write "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"?

As non-root user by the name of "user1" I did:

```
# multi-user install
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable

# add user1 to rvm group
sudo adduser user1 rvm

source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Then I exit the shell and start a new one:

```
user1@72265e666e07:/$ rvm -v
bash: rvm: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at answers for this [question](https://superuser.com/a/183980/277312):

> From your problem description it seems that the rvm script needs to be
>   loaded only once, during login. As far as I know, Ubuntu reads
>   `/etc/profile/` and `~/.profile` during login (the graphical login,
>   independent of bash). That means, after logging out and a logging in
>   once, the rvm script should be active. If it still doesn't work, then
>   perhaps the rvm script needs to be loaded for every bash session. If
>   that is the case then `bashrc` is the more appropriate place for the
>   script.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and come back with the results.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got me on the right track and I have now solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that rvm was not in any of my bash init files. I thought that that should be installed/configured automatically when installing rvm, but apparently it was not!
I had to run the two following commands to add rvm initialization globally for every user.

```
printf '\n\nif [ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then\n  . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"\nelif [ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then\n  . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"\nfi' >> /etc/profile
printf '\n\nif [ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then\n  . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"\nelif [ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then\n  . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"\nfi' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

After I had run these two commands it is possible to reach rvm directly when I log in to my user "user1".